# How to handle concurrent request in Web Service in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web method exposed in web-service in ASP.net. On request i am fetching record from database and start the transaction. in transaction i update the record and perform other operations and commit the transaction. now another request came from web method and get the same record while another transaction is going on. 
I am using dirty read with (noLock) , if i remove nolock causing time out. i am using ASP.net with vb and sql server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Try to lock the record when you are ready to update and keep the lock time to the minimum. If you need to detect if the record was updated between the read and write operation, grab a timestamp when reading the record and see if the timestamp was changed when ready to write the changes. If the timestamp is not the same, you have detected that some other thread updated the record, and your changes no longer valid.

Comment: locking the record can helpful if other request came after start the transaction, Request can come in microseconds before starts the transaction actually.